# Insert a row in MySQL using C++ for MFC Dialog Base App

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++, mfc

I have 2 variables, and I want to insert their values into a MySQL database, but I don't know how to do this.

Here is the all of my code so far, please correct/advise:

```
void RegistrationForm::Register()
{
    istifadeciAdi.GetWindowText(i_ad);
    par.GetWindowText(i_par);
    parTekrar.GetWindowText(i_par_tekrar);

if (istifadeciAdi.GetWindowTextLength() != 0) // if you can please write this line better.
{
    if (i_parol == i_parol_tekrar)
    {
        MySQL_Driver *driver;
        Connection *dbConn;
        Statement *statement;
        //ResultSet *result; // I don't need this line any more
        //PreparedStatement *ps;

        driver = get_mysql_driver_instance();
        dbConn = driver->connect("host", "u", "c");

        dbConn->setSchema("mfc_app_database");
        statement = dbConn->createStatement();

        statement->executeQuery("INSERT INTO users(`username`, `password`) VALUES (/* how to use i_ad and i_par as variable to set column value? */)"); // executes the user "input"

        /*ps = dbConn->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users(`username`, `password`, `name`) VALUES (?)");
        ps->setString(1, "cccc");
        ps->setString(2, "ffff);*/

        //delete result;
        //delete[] result;
        /*delete ps;
        delete[] ps;*/
        delete statement;
        delete[] statement; // don't use this line in your program as me
        delete dbConn;
        delete[] dbConn; // don't use this line in your program as me
    }
    else
        MessageBox(L"Şifrə dəqiq təkrar olunmalıdır.", L"Xəbərdarlıq", MB_ICONWARNING);
}
else
    AfxMessageBox(L"Boş qoymaq olmaz.");
}
```

### Edit

There's no any error. But when I clicked the (Register) button it says:
`Program stopped working`
and after clicking the `Debug` button it takes me to line which insert query I wrote.

p.s Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You are going to have to tell us what exactly is not working. Post error messages and any additional information you might have.

Comment: @MichaelOryl please, read question again. I just edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CString` to make query.
For example:

```
CString strQuery;
strQuery.Format(_T("INSERT INTO users(`username`, `password`) VALUES ('%s', '%s')"),i_ad, i_par);
```

Before using this query string in `executeQuery` (or in other query commands) you must convert it to `std::string`. Because, `execute, executeQuery and executeUpdate` commands **only accepts** the `std::string`.So, add this lines:

`CT2CA tempString(query);`

`std::string query(tempString);`

And use this string in your execute command

```
statement->executeQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-cpp-en.a4.pdf) for that MySQL connector say to use `statement::execute()` for queries that don't return a resultset, and `statement::executeQuery()` when there is a single row resultset.

So for SQL `INSERT INTO` maybe your problem is that you should be using `execute`.

Comment: I read it. And I also accepted an answer and edited it.
Thanks!